# Google cloud storage authorization

Tags: google-cloud-platform, authorization, google-cloud-storage

I have a Google Cloud Storage Bucket with uniform access control and I've added "allUsers" to the permissions. It says the object is public but I still get this message, when I try to open the link:
*"Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object"*
The error code is "401". I would like any user to be able to access the link. How can I do that? Thanks in advance!

Best regards,
Ben

Comment: Which role did you grant on `allUsers` generic account?

Comment: I've tried both "reader" and "owner", but I still get the same message.

Comment: SOLUTION: I set the role of allUsers to Reader of Storage Objects. Works now, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As said on the comments, you need to assign to `allUsers` the role `Reader`, as shown in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public#objects).